# How to decode springDeserializerExceptionValue to string?

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I'm getting the error below as result of a `kafka avro` `deserialisation` error but the message body is printed as numbers ranging from `-128` to `128`.

How do I convert this to a readable string?

```
Backoff none exhausted for ConsumerRecord(topic = gcrs_process_events, partition = 2, leaderEpoch = 153, offset = 204901345, LogAppendTime = 1647242630166, serialized key size = 36, serialized value size = 210, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = springDeserializerExceptionValue, value = [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, 69, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 115, 117, 112, 112, 111, 114, 116, 46, 115, 101, 114, 105, 97, 108, 105, 122, 101, 114, 46, 68, 101, 115, 101, 114, 105, 97, 108, 105, 122, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, -26, -50, 105, 87, -16, 47, -111, -25, 2, 0, 2, 90, 0, 5, 105, 115, 75, 101, 121, 91, 0, 4, 100, 97, 116, 97, 116, 0, 2, 91, 66, 120, 114, 0, 40, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 67, 55, -37, -114, ........
```

Comment: Could you please give us your Kafka bean configuration?

Answer (score 3):

The deserialization exception header is a binary value (the result of using Java serialization on the exception).

You can use `ListenerUtils.getExceptionFromHeader()` to convert it back to the exception.

```java
/**
 * Extract a {@link DeserializationException} from the supplied header name, if
 * present.
 * @param record the consumer record.
 * @param headerName the header name.
 * @param logger the logger for logging errors.
 * @return the exception or null.
 * @since 2.3
 */
@Nullable
public static DeserializationException getExceptionFromHeader(final ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record,
        String headerName, LogAccessor logger) {
```

See the code in the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` for an example:

```java
DeserializationException vDeserEx = ListenerUtils.getExceptionFromHeader(record,
        SerializationUtils.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER, this.logger);
DeserializationException kDeserEx = ListenerUtils.getExceptionFromHeader(record,
        SerializationUtils.KEY_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER, this.logger);
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, now I see the error message if the exception but I was hoping to see the kafka message with the incorrect schema etc. Is it possible? record.value() is null inside `factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler((record, exception)->{} )`

Comment: The value that couldn't be decoded is available in a property of the exception. I am not at a computer. I think it is called data.

Comment: @GaryRussell how to do the same in Spring Kafka 3.1?

Comment: There are no changes to this mechanism in 3.1.